# How to deal with impossible hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

I am wondering if there is any recommended way of dealing with impossible hyphenations like the one from the first line, in the middle.

If the column width will be bigger, it would be easier to handle it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[english,romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 bottom=15mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\selectlanguage{english}
It was her way of asking him to share his private thoughts with her. When others asked his private thoughts, he felt spied upon. But Jiang-qing asked only so that she could also think the same thought; it was part of their having become a single soul.
\switchcolumn
\selectlanguage{romanian}
--\,Era felul ei de a-i cere s\u{a}-i \^{i}mp\u{a}rt\u{a}\c{s}easc\u{a} g\^{a}ndurile intime. C\^{a}nd al\c{t}ii \^{i}l \^{i}ntrebau despre g\^{a}nduri ascunse, se sim\c{t}ea iscodit. Dar Jiang-Qing \^{i}ntreba numai ca s\u{a} se poat\u{a} g\^{a}ndi \c{s}i ea la acela\c{s}i lucru; era un mod de manifestare a faptului c\u{a} deveniser\u{a} un suflet unic.

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example picture]

Comment: To rephrase the sentence is not possible in a translated document. Also, imagine you will change the font of the text size of the document in future, how would you deal with all small overflows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: THE BEST package I ever saw. Always ON from now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
\spaceskip=.33333em plus .2em  minus .083333em
\xspaceskip=1em plus .5em minus .25em
\nonfrenchspacing
```

gives

[image]

setting the space between words to a 1/3 em +/- and the space between sentences to one em +/-. `\nonfrenchspacing` activates the separate spacing between sentences, which can be more flexible than that between words without being as unsightly.